# Is it possible to use multiple mail accounts at the same time in Office 365?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I would like to use multiple mail accounts in the online version of Office 365 (Mail section of login.microsoftonline.com). At the moment, I can just log in with one account. If I want to check the mail belonging to an other account, I have to log off and log in with the other account. It is not possible to open two different accounts: when you open login.microsoftonline.com in a second tab, it automatically logs in to the account that was already open in a first tab.
Are there any alternatives to circumvent this situation (online)?

Comment: An alternative is of course to read mails belonging to one account in a web browser and mails belonging to an other account in Microsoft Outlook; or to read everything in Microsoft Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible - though not elegant - solution is to open each account in a different web browser (e.g. Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Or to use the "profiles" feature of a single Web browser.